# perfect variable separation, determine cutoff via ROCR package in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, separation

I am developing a logistic regression model where perfect variable separation occurs. I want to calculate a cutoff from this data. Interestingly, the length of the slot `cutoffs` of `pred.obj` is only 5, as well as the slots `fp`, `tp`, `tn`, `fn`, `n.pos.pred` and `n.neg.pred`. I expect it to have the same length as the observations.

Has anybody an explanation for this? (And knows how to solve it?)

MWE:

```
 library(ROCR) # package for prediction/performance functions
 y <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
 x <- c(-5, 5, 3, -2, 4, 3, -8, 2, 5, 3, -5, -3, -2)
 model <- glm(as.factor(y) ~ x, family = "binomial")
 preds <- predict(model, type = "response")
 (pred.obj <- prediction(preds, y))
 perf <- performance(pred.obj, "acc")
 (cutoff <- perf@x.values[[1]][which.max(perf@y.values[[1]])])
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your predictions. If you take a look at them, you only have four possible outcomes `table(preds)`, which I would consider just as two (0 and 1). One option would be to include the linear predictor instead of the response to compute the ROC curve. That way you get eight different predictions and so nine values for each slot. Anyways, I would not feel comfortable working with that model (look at the standard errors). I suggest using Firth's method, which can deal with perfect separation problems such as this one providing reasonable estimates:

```
library(brglm)
model <- brglm(y ~ x, family = "binomial")
preds <- predict(model)
(pred.obj <- prediction(preds, y))
perf <- performance(pred.obj, "acc")
(cutoff <- perf@x.values[[1]][which.max(perf@y.values[[1]])])
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I wanted to use anyway the model with Firth penalisation, I was just curious about what caused this behaviour. Thanks again! (I will vote this answer up as soon as I have a reputation of 15)